# Compare local and remote files on FTP with WinSCP lib

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, synchronization, winscp

How i can check updates via WinSCP on FTP server with .NET?

I'm using `SynchronizationMode.Local`

For example:

```
if(have_new_update){
    MessageBox("U can update")
    if(ok){
        update();
    }
}else{
    return;
}
```

My code:

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions {
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp, HostName = ftp_url, UserName = username, Password = pass
};
using (Session session = new Session()) {
    rtb_update_material.AppendText("\nConnected\n");
    //Transferring
    session.FileTransferred += FileTransferred;
    session.FileTransferProgress += SessionProgressBar;
    session.Open(sessionOptions);
    SynchronizationResult synchronizationResult;
    synchronizationResult = session.SynchronizeDirectories(SynchronizationMode.Local, @"MyPath\", "/", true);

    synchronizationResult.Check();
    if (synchronizationResult.IsSuccess)
        rtb_update_material.AppendText("Done\n");
```

Comment: What updates? Updates of files? There's no `SynchronizationMode` in your code example.

Comment: I need to find out if there are any files to update to display a notification about this to the user

Comment: So do you need to compare some local files against remote files to find if there are newer files in the local folder that need to be uploaded to a remote folder?

Comment: yes, and if i have a diff, i want to show a messegebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Session.CompareDirectories`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_comparedirectories) to find the differences between a local and a remote directory:

```
var diffs =
    session.CompareDirectories(SynchronizationMode.Remote, localPath, remotePath, false);

if (diffs.Count > 0) 
{
    // there are differences
}
```

Comment: session.CompareDirectories(SynchronizationMode.Remote
*Local


Thanx!

Comment: If you are updating remote files, use `.Remote`.